# Info.plist file for framework missing in cordova app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins, appstore-approval

I have a cordova app which when compiled and run in device is working well, but when I upload it in the app store. The "Build is invalid". and also i got this email from apple:  iTunes Connect

```
Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,  APP_NAME.
```

Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

```
1.) This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/APP_NAME.app/www/js/cordova-ios/tests/spec/unit/fixtures/org.test.plugins.dummyplugin/src/ios/Custom.framework is missing or could not be read.

2.) Invalid Bundle - The bundle at '/Payload/APP_NAME.app/www/js/cordova-ios/tests/spec/unit/fixtures/org.test.plugins.dummyplugin/src/ios/Custom.framework' does not contain a bundle executable.

3.) This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/APP_NAME.app/www/js/cordova-ios/tests/spec/unit/fixtures/org.test.plugins.dummyplugin/src/ios/CustomEmbeddable.framework is missing or could not be read.

4.) Invalid Bundle - The bundle at '/Payload/APP_NAME.app/www/js/cordova-ios/tests/spec/unit/fixtures/org.test.plugins.dummyplugin/src/ios/CustomEmbeddable.framework' does not contain a bundle executable.
```

Can not seem to find a reason. How can the build work in local device but when build and archived and uploaded, its invalid build.

Thanks in advance :)

my config file content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.docandtrack.app" version="2.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>Doc and Track</name>
<description>
    An App for Truckers to use the Doc and Track system
</description>
<author email="email" href="endpoint link">
    Doc and Track
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1500" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/android/screen.9.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/android/screen.9.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/android/screen.9.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/android/screen.9.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/android/screen.9.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/android/screen.9.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/android/screen.9.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/android/screen.9.png" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="res/android/icon-ldpi.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="res/android/icon-mdpi.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="res/android/icon-hdpi.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/android/icon-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/android/icon-xxhdpi.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/android/icon-xxxhdpi.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="deployment-target" value="10.0" />
    <splash height="480" src="res/ios/screen/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    <splash height="960" src="res/ios/screen/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1024" src="res/ios/screen/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="2048" src="res/ios/screen/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="768" src="res/ios/screen/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="1536" src="res/ios/screen/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="1136" src="res/ios/screen/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="res/ios/screen/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="res/ios/screen/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" src="res/ios/screen/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <icon height="20" src="res/ios/icon-20.png" width="20" />
    <icon height="40" src="res/ios/icon-20@2x.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="180" src="res/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="120" src="res/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="167" src="res/ios/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="152" src="res/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="76" src="res/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="80" src="res/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="60" src="res/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="87" src="res/ios/icon-29@3x.png" width="87" />
    <icon height="58" src="res/ios/icon-29@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="29" src="res/ios/icon-29.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="114" src="res/ios/icon-57@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="57" src="res/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="100" src="res/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="50" src="res/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="144" src="res/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="72" src="res/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="1024" src="res/ios/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
</platform>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="~1.5.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-datepicker" spec="~0.9.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="docandtrack-image-plugin" />
<plugin name="com.transistorsoft.cordova.background-geolocation" spec="https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation.git" />
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSMotionUsageDescription">
    <string>Using the accelerometer increases battery-efficiency by intelligently toggling location-tracking only when the device is detected to be moving</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
    <string>Photo library is required for storing documents</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
    <string>Camera is required for storing documents</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription">
    <string>Background location-tracking is required for route mapping</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
    <string>Location tracking is required for route mapping</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationUsageDescription">
    <string>Location tracking is required for route mapping</string>
</edit-config>
<preference name="cordova-background-geolocation-license" value="xxxxxxxxxxx" />
<preference name="cordova-background-geolocation-orderId" value="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#2C3642" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="blackopaque" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.4.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^5.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" spec="^1.3.0">
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="27.+" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-sim" spec="~1.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="^2.2.0">
    <variable name="XWALK_VERSION" value="23+" />
    <variable name="XWALK_LITEVERSION" value="xwalk_core_library_canary:17+" />
    <variable name="XWALK_COMMANDLINE" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
    <variable name="XWALK_MODE" value="embedded" />
    <variable name="XWALK_MULTIPLEAPK" value="true" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
<engine name="android" spec="^6.3.0" />
<engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.4" />
</widget>
```

more info:

my cordova version is 8.0.0
Installed platforms:

Installed platforms:
  android 6.3.0
  ios 4.5.4

My www folder structure screen shots:

[image: Platform folder structure]

[image: WWW folder structure]

here are my js folder content:

[image: js folder content 1]

[image: js folder content 2]

Comment: Could you add your config.xml or at least share what plugins you are using?

Comment: @Phonolog i have added my config file content

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your www folder? Is it a regular Cordova app or you use some framework to build the app? Do you use some bundler?

Comment: Can you try to generate an .ipa and install in your phone through hockeyApp may be? to check if its all good. That way you will get more picture whats going wrong.

Comment: @KarthickRamesh not app hockey but did install both debug and distribution and they are working fine. Only app store upload has the problem.

Comment: @jcesarmobile screenshots has been  added.

Comment: on the second screenshot, can you also expand the js folder? You are using yarn, right? it's possible that it's not compatible with Cordova (but didn't try)

Comment: @jcesarmobile my best guess is something being wrong while archiving like something isnt geting bundled because app is working file in debug and distribution. Any idea?

Comment: No, the problem is you or something (yarn?) is adding cordova-ios to your app, that's why I want you to show the js folder, to see if cordova-ios is there already or if it's being added afterwards.

Comment: @jcesarmobile I have added js folder content image. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have the whole `cordova-ios` library code inside your `js` folder. As you have all `cordova-ios` code, it also contain the tests, which includes the `dummyplugin` test, which has the invalid custom frameworks that don't pass Apple validation.

You don't have to add it, neither `cordova-android` or any of the plugins and libs you have there. For now remove the whole cordova-ios folder and build your app again.

The needed `cordova-ios` code and the plugins code is generated by `cordova prepare` command and copied to the proper `appName/platforms/ios/www` folder.

Comment: I dont recall doing anything like that, adding it myself there. 
What might be the solution to this now?

Comment: Remove cordova-ios, cordova-android and probably everything else that you are not really using from the js folder.